# How to multiplex several light sources into one optical path?

Tags: optics

I'd like to design a device that takes 4 channels of light from sets of LEDs and multiplexes them into one optical path, which finally creates a rectangle pattern of light that is approximately 30mm tall and 1mm wide. This is to be used with a line scan camera. In practice, only one of the 4 channels would be illuminated at any given time.

Here's a rough drawing of what I'm imagining:

[image: sketch of a multiplexing setup]

I've thought about doing it with mirrors as shown below, but obviously my LEDs are not perfectly collimated sources of light so this would not work. Perhaps this can be solved with a pair of convex cylindrical lenses facing each other to roughly collimate the light, but that would require a lot of lenses and money. [This paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8493314) also has a very nice and purportedly low cost TIR + Fresnel lens setup that collimates and shapes the light into a pattern suitable for line scan cameras.

[image]

I've also seen a lab setup in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.3390/app8050719), but once again my light sources are not collimated and I suspect a lot of light would be lost to the beam splitters. The [LEDs I'm using](https://cree-led.com/media/documents/XLampXPE2.pdf) are in the 100s of lumens.

[image: multiplexing setup from a paper]

I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction on this design problem. I'm familiar with the basics of optics, but clearly I'm not an expert. Thank you.

Comment: since only one source is illuminated at any one time, arrange the leds in a semicircle and place a pivoting mirror at the center of the semicircle ... use lenses between the led and the mirror, if needed

Comment: Please don't duplicate posts in different groups -- or at least not without deleting the previous post and explaining why you moved groups.

Comment: The pivoting mirror is my backup plan, I would prefer to have a solution with no moving parts. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Deleting the previous post seems counter-productive since there are some good proposals there, why should valuable information be erased? Furthermore, there's now a warning on the question itself saying that the question is off topic.